# Find the point(s) on the graph of$ f$ where the tangent line is horizontal.

Tags: calculus

How do I Find the point(s) on the graph of f where the tangent line is horizontal? 
$f(x) = (x^2 + 8)(5 − x)$.

Comment: Is this for class? If so, what have you discussed in class?

Comment: What's the slope of a line that's parallel to $x$-axis?

Answer (score 0):

A line is horizontal when its slope is zero. The slope of the tangent line is the derivative of the function. In other words the question is asking you for what $x$ is $f'(x)=0$?

$f(x)=(x^2+8)(5-x) = -x^3+5x^2-8x+40$

$f'(x)=(-3x^2+10x-8)$

$x=\frac{-10\pm\sqrt{100-96}}{-6}=\frac{-10\pm 2}{-6}=2,\frac{4}{3}$

$(2,36)$ and $\left(\frac{4}{3},\frac{968}{27}\right)$ are the only points where the tangent line is horizontal.